# process sub query which returns multiple rows for each row. Db: Mysql, sql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I wish to process each result of subquery but it is not happening. Ultimately i wish to sum all the differences of each result.

```
    SELECT e.event_id
    ,TIMEDIFF((
            SELECT event_suppress_endtime
            FROM eventedge_event_acknowledgements ak
            WHERE e.event_id = ak.event_id
            ), (
            SELECT event_suppress_starttime
            FROM eventedge_event_acknowledgements ak
            WHERE e.event_id = ak.event_id
            ))
FROM events e;
```

Here each subquery returns multiple values. I wish to find timediff and then total it!

Below is schema of data:
[acknowledgement table with event-id as parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ONgm.png)

Desired O/p:
sum(timediff)
200 seconds

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be able to pull this off more easily with a join:

```
SELECT e.event_id, TIMEDIFF(event_suppress_endtime, event_suppress_starttime)
FROM events e
INNER JOIN eventedge_event_acknowledgements ak
ON e.event_id = ak.event_id
```

Comment: Cool - glad I could help